# How to change MySQL status variables?

Tags: mysql

How can I change Mysql system status variables? I need to increase value for `Ssl_default_timeout`.

Here is more about status variables:

- http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/server-status-variables.html

Answer (score 2):

Status variables are normally just counters and current values for objects whose state changes. There are some exceptions.

**EXCEPTION #1** : Some status variables are statically compiled-in, such as [innodb_page_size](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Innodb_page_size).

**EXCEPTION #2** : That particular status variable, [**Ssl_default_timeout**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Ssl_default_timeout), cannot change. It has to be supplied from external means. Evidently, there exists no particular CLI method to change it.

Since [OpenSSL has function calls to change timeout values](https://www.openssl.org/docs/ssl/SSL_CTX_set_timeout.html), my guess is that mysqld probably retrieves this value from the OS if SSL libraries make it available to do so. If you are able to make such function calls, you may have to restart mysqld if [**Ssl_default_timeout**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/server-status-variables.html#statvar_Ssl_default_timeout) does not change automatically.